# How to transform array of objects to new array of objects and count the keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The code is something like this:

```
let inputArray=[
{Id: '1', Name: 'Ani'},
{Id: '2', Name: 'George'},
{Id: '4', Name: 'George'},
{Id: '5', Name: 'Ani'}];
```

I need to make a new array with objects in the format :

```
let result=[
{ Name: 'Ani', count:2},
{ Name: 'George',count:2},
{ Name: 'Henry',count:1}];
```

Any idea please? :)

Comment: inputArray.map(({Name,Id})=>({Name,count:Id}))

Comment: Please explain how this dude, Henry is all of a sudden in the output array when he wasn't in the input array?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a Hash & Array.reduce here.

```
const hash = inputArray.reduce((memo, item) => {
  memo[item.Name] = memo[item.Name] || {name: item.Name, count: 0}
  memo[item.Name].count++
  return memo
}, {})

result = Object.values(hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to count the repetition of any field given the field name

```js
let inputArray=[
{Id: '1', Name: 'Ani'},
{Id: '2', Name: 'George'},
{Id: '4', Name: 'George'},
{Id: '5', Name: 'Ani'}];




function countFields(input, field){
  const count = {};
  
  input.forEach(e =>{
    const v = e[field];
    if(!count[v])count[v] = 0;
    count[v]++;
  })
  
  return count;
  
}

const result = countFields(inputArray, "Name")

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with reduce:

```js
let inputArray = [
{Id: '1', Name: 'Ani'},
{Id: '2', Name: 'George'},
{Id: '4', Name: 'George'},
{Id: '5', Name: 'Ani'}];

const counts = inputArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const valIndex = acc.findIndex(val => val.name === curr.Name)
    if(valIndex >= 0) {acc[valIndex].count += 1}
  else {
    acc.push({name: curr.Name, count: 1})
  }
  return acc
}, [])
```